# Save excel file with xlsm extension in PHP

Tags: php, excel, xlsm

A very narrow problem here.
Trying to upload excel file with ext 'xlsm'
The code runs but it saves the file with 'xlsx' extension instead, and then cannot open the file beacsue the extension is wrong.

Have this:

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
if (false === $ext = array_search($finfo->file($_FILES['upfiles1']['tmp_name']),
    array(
    'doc' => 'application/msword',
    'docx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
    'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
    'xlsx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    'xlsm' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12', // macro xls files
    'csv' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'xls' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel'),
                true
            )) {
                throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
            }
$fullname = $_POST['filename'] . "." . $ext;
$fulldir = sprintf($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\xxx\%s', $fullname);
if (file_exists($fulldir)) {
    $okproc = $okproc + 1;
    if (!unlink($fulldir)) {  
        $status = "old file" . $fullname . " cannot be replaced due to an error. Contact admin.";
    }                       
} else {
    $sqlFileLog = "INSERT INTO FilesLogExt (FileGroup, RefID, DateUploaded, FileName) VALUES ('2', '" . $tID . "', SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '" . $fullname . "'); ";
    $result = $conn->query($sqlFileLog);
    if($result) {
        $okproc = $okproc + 1;
    }
}
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upfiles1']['tmp_name'], $fulldir)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
} else {
    $okproc = $okproc + 1;
}
```

I tried to change the order but it still save macro file into ext 'xlsx'

Appreciate any advice!
Thank you!

Comment: What about switching lines 6 and 7 (`xlsm` before `xlsx`)?

Comment: You don't show any code that saves the file.

Comment: Also, what is `echo $finfo->file($_FILES['upfiles1']['tmp_name']);`

Comment: edited to show how I save the file. switched lines - still saves with xlsx